Error occurs on a MediaTek device: com.mediatek.view.impl.MsyncFactoryImpl
I am currently building an app.
The app utilizes the notification. Error occured on my phone Redmi Note 9 that has a MTK processor Helio g85. But when i run the app on emulator the error wont show.
What should be the fix??
Notification should appear when the input date matches of the date today
